# How to make the registration details available to main page in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, session

I am building a web application which has a registration page ,login page and main page. User enters details in registration page for the first time(username,password,mail id,phone number) and on successive visits enters details in login page(Username and password only)
I need the following to be achieved

- Make the mail id that the user gave on registration available to the main page

My code for this

```
   //Code in registration page for fetching mail id
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["txt1"] = TextBoxname.Text;

    }
   //code for displaying the mail id fetched from registration page
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {   

      WelcomeUsername.Text = (string)Session["txt1"];
       }
```

I am not able to display the mail id because the registration page is used only for a single time that is during registration but if a regular user logs in the user will fill details in login page.So how can I make the registration details available to main page in case of regular user(one who is not using registration page each and every time).Please help.I am new to .Net.Thanks in advance

Comment: Better do more research with this buddy! I believe this is not a homework?

Comment: just store the required information to your database. you can use sessions, but asp.net already has a default authentication helper which you can inspect by creating a new Project from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Session won't last forever.

Pseudocode would be something considering that you want to do the way you mentioned:

1. Store user data somewhere (database, file, etc.) and store ID in the Session
2. Get ID from the Session
3. Find the required ID in the database and retrieve the needed info (in your case e-mail)

Comment: I have created a database already to store all the details but could be please tell me how to store ID in session please ? @Hrvach

Comment: After adding to the database just use `Session["ID"] = //pass the value with the database value`

Answer (score 0):

its simple use, put the email textbox value below here

```
formsauthentication.setauthCookie(email.text,false)
```

and use   asp:loginView for login thats it ,hope this helps you

Comment: Could you please explain me step by step? @dazzling Kumar